# react table - useMemo vs useState

Tags: reactjs, memoization, react-table, react-table-v7

The [react table documentation](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable) says that the data values should be memoized.  However, in some of their examples on the site, they use useState instead of useMemo.  Is useState already memoized? If not, what issues might I run into if the data is not memoized? (or how should it be done correctly when needing to change the data?) TIA!

[documentation link with example of useState](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/examples/editable-data) ([link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v7/examples/editable-data) in case documentation link becomes 404 like a lot of old posts linking to old versions of react table documentation that I've come across)

Answer (score 2):

I am not answering your question, but to show you the possible reason why they use **useState** against their **Must be memoized** statement.

Let's see react's documentation about **useMemo** & **useState**:

> **useMemo** will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed. This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on every render.

> **useState** Returns a stateful value, and a function to update it.

The first example is where the memoized dependencies **rawData** are passed down from its parent component and we want to customize the data by using **expensiveMakeDataCalculation** method. Here, the table data is renewed when changes of **rawData** are detected and we use **useMemo** for the sake of **optimization**, as the docs said.

```
function ExampleA({ rawData }) {
   const data = useMemo(() => expensiveMakeDataCalculation(rawData), [rowData]);
   ...
}
```

But how if we want to fetch the data within the component? Yes, we can use **useState** to store our fetched data. As we know that **rawData** will always be the most recent state after applying updates and the memoized **data** will be renewed once **rawData** state changes.

```
function ExampleB({ initialData }) {
   const [rawData, setRawData] = useState(initialData);

   const data = useMemo(() => expensiveMakeDataCalculation(rawData), [rawData]);

   // for example only
   const onClick = (id) => {
     try {
        const res = await fetch(`url/${id}`);
        const fetchedData = await res.json();
        setRawData(fetchedData);
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
     }

   }
   ...
}
```

Here, we can simplify the code as below. We do not use **useMemo** anymore, since we are confident that the **expensiveMakeDataCalculation** only runs when the **onCLick** method is called and the **data** state can be consumed immediately by your table. You can memoize the **data** by using **useMemo**, but I think it is not necessary.

```
function ExampleC({ initialData }) {
   const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

   // for example only
   const onClick = (id) => {
     try {
        const res = await fetch(`url/${id}`);
        const rawData = await res.json();
        const calculatedData = expensiveMakeDataCalculation(rawData);
        setData(calculatedData);
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
     }

   }
   ...
}
```

So, based on the above example, we can have new insight into how [this](https://github.com/TanStack/table/blob/v7/examples/editable-data/src/App.js) example works and know the reason why the example uses **useState** over their **Must be memoized** statement. Here, the **expensiveMakeDataCalculation** is called inside **setData** setter and only runs when **updateMyData** method called.

```
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => makeData(20))
 
  const updateMyData = (rowIndex, columnId, value) => {
    ...
    setData(old =>
      // expensiveMakeDataCalculation. expensive? yes if you have a lot of rows data
      old.map((row, index) => {
        if (index === rowIndex) {
          return {
            ...old[rowIndex],
            [columnId]: value,
          }
        }
        return row
      })
    )
  }
```