# react-table: do I need memoize data even when fetching data with a useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, memoization, react-table

In the react-table docs examples, the input data to the table is memoized for the following reason:

> React Table relies on memoization to determine when state and side
> effects should update or be calculated. This means that every option
> you pass to useTable should be memoized either via `React.useMemo` (for
> objects) or `React.useCallback` (for functions).

All their examples use locally defined javascript objects. If I were to fetch data from a server in a `useEffect` hook, and add it to the component's state, do I still need to memoize it with useMemo? If so, should this memoization take place within or outside `useEffect`?  I'm still wrapping my head around these React hooks and when/if they should be used together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason for using **useMemo** or **useCallback** is **optimization**

So, if you fetch data from a server in an optimized **useEffect**, let's say it only runs after the initial render, and put the result inside a state via **useState**, then you do not need **useMemo** to memoized the state anymore even if there is a **heavyCalculation** inside it. Why? because the **heavyCalculation** (if any) will only run once and the state will never change, so it will never affect the **react-table** performance.

```
const URL = 'https://for.example.only'

function heavyCalculation(data) {
  ...
}

function Example() {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchData = async () => {
       try {
         const response = await fetch(URL);
         const responseJson = await response.json();

         if (!response.ok) {
           throw new Error(responseJson.status_message);
         }

         const updatedData = heavyCalculation(responseJson);
         setData(updatedData);
       } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
       }
     }
     fetchData();
   },[])
   ...
}
```

You can see another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73482069/8198873).

Comment: Just to clarify the way you're fetching data in this example: the fetch logic should be placed into an async function right?  You're using the await keyword on it's own and I haven't seen that before.